# How can I switch back to Nvidia card from Intel with Nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

So I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 and found that the `primusrun` command no longer works, so ditched `bumblebee` in favour of `nvidia-prime`. This lets you switch video card from nvidia-settings rather than running through the command line (I prefer the old method, but want the primus performance).

The problem is that after switching to Intel from nvidia-settings, I can no longer open it up again to switch back to the nvidia card. When I open nvidia-settings I get a segmentation fault (according to the terminal).

Is there any way to open nvidia-settings switch back? I would like the ability to be able to switch between the two since having the nvidia card on all the time kills my battery and heats up the laptop a lot.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a bug (LP [#1214508](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/1214508)).

You can switch using:

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Also, Bumblebee is still supported so you can install it if you prefer. You'll have to remove `nvidia-prime` then as you can't use both.

Comment: Yes, that worked (after logging out and back in). Thank you! I do prefer using bumblebee, but after the update to 14.04, only optirun worked and not primusrun (everything I ran gave a segmentation fault). Ideally, I would like to return to using the primusrun command, but if this is the only way I can get the extra performance, then I'll use this.