# 14.04 with nVidia 800m Series Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 14.04, nvidia-optimus

I have recently bought a Sager NP7338 laptop which has the 860M nVidia GeForce card on it with Optimus Technology.

**Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize that I have a nVidia graphics card at all.**

Is this the root of my problem and the reason why I cannot get it to work or is this normal with the Optimus Technology?

I have figured out that I can use both graphics cards (because there is also a dedicate Intel Graphics card) with nvidia-prime from this question: [How can I switch back to Nvidia card from Intel with Nvidia-prime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459315/how-can-i-switch-back-to-nvidia-card-from-intel-with-nvidia-prime)

Comment: So, have you installed `nvidia-prime`?

Comment: I messed up my Xorg file on my last install so I just reinstalled it. I will install nvidia-prime now

Comment: I tried to solve my problem at this URL [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html) but I'll tell you how it works out.

Comment: Okay the posted solution does work at the link I provided but take into consideration that you have to log out and log back in to get nVidia graphics card to work. It may be a pain in the butt, however I don't mind using that method over bumblebee since I seemed to not understand how to use it and using `nvidia-prime` is loads easier