# Why do I have two drivers for my display?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness

I have bought a new laptop recently it is the Asus K555LD and I have ubuntu 14.04 installed and up to date.
One of the problem I faced is finding the driver for my nVidia GeForce 820M. After some time of searching and struggling I installed it using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Now when I type the command: `sudo lshw -c video` I get the following output:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:63 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

so I am a little confused because as long as I know I don't have an intel device, and then in order to know which driver the system is using I ran the command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
```

the output was:

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

so my question is why do I have two drivers? and how can I use the nVidia one?

Comment: You probably have two graphic chips, one on-board (Intel) and one full card (nVidia). I don't know if this is true or why one would build this into a laptop, but that would be an explanation. You see both devices have different PCI bus addresses, so I doubt it could be two driver modules for the same device. P.S: Please ask only one question per post, so remove your last paragraph and tag and open a new question for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx, I have removed my second question. and about my first question how do I tell the system to use the nvidia device?

Comment: If I was sure about that, I would have posted an answer! :) Sorry, but I just don't know...

Comment: you can use nvidia `prime-select <card>` option more detailed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412452/getting-hybrid-graphics-to-work-nvidia-prime-gt650m) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459315/how-can-i-switch-back-to-nvidia-card-from-intel-with-nvidia-prime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the software and updates GUI, look at the Additional Drivers tab, and select the NVIDIA driver for your device You should not have to use 3rd party repositories for this.

Comment: Actually, the xswat ppa is fine and has a slightly more upto date version of the driver, worth a look for desktop users who play demanding games

Comment: I have done it the way you said and now in the additional drivers tab it shows that I am using the nvidia driver but when running `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'` I am still getting `Kernel driver in use: i915` not nvidia.

Comment: You should read about Bumblebee, as Mentioned in Mark's answer. Basically, your laptop graphics driver is designed to switch between a low-energy intel driver and a high-energy nvidia driver based on the performance needs.

Comment: I have gone with your answer. now I can choose whether to use nvidia or intel device in the `nvidia-settings` command. I don't need it to be done automatically by Bumblebee as I am using my laptop for development.

Answer (score 1):

You have a hybrid GPU (nvidia and intel) you can use bumbblebee to tak advantage of this, by default it uses the intel but the usage section will show you how to use the Nvidia

### Important first step

Remove the driver you installed like this, a diffrent one will be installed later

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

This should cover any Bumblebee / optiumus questions you have, but for more information you can see the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

### Install on 12.04

You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below.

If on 12.04.3, replace `linux-headers-generic` with `linux-headers-generic-lts-raring`

Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories - you need to do this to allow the bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively to be installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Bumblebee using the default proprietary nvidia driver for 12.04 - 13.04 :

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot

### Basic Setup for 13.10 and later

You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot

### Advanced Setups

For advanced users, if you do not want to use the proprietary nvidia driver or 32-bit libraries (for example, if you are only interested in power savings), you can do your custom installation.

Minimal setup :

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee
```

Depending on your needs, add to this line:

```
bumblebee-nvidia: proprietary nvidia driver support (if installed, become default over nouveau)
```

virtualgl: VirtualGL as backend

`virtualgl-libs-ia32:` 32bit support for VirtualGL on 64bit system, necessary to run 32bit app through optirun

`primus: primus/primusrun` as backend (virtualgl Stays default, you need to run optirun -b primus )

`primus-libs-ia32:` 32bit support for primus/primurun on 64bit system, necessary to run 32bit app through optirun

### Usage

To run your application with the discrete NVIDIA card run in the terminal:

```
optirun [options] <application> [application-parameters]
```

Example:

```
optirun firefox
```

For a list of options for optirun run:

```
optirun --help
```

Normally you do not use optirun for your window manager, installations or other non graphic heavy demanding programs. The optirun command is mainly used for graphic demanding programs or for games.

### Power Management

A primary goal of this project is to not only enable use of the discrete GPU for rendering, but also to enable smart power management of the dGPU when it's not in use. We're using either bbswitch (a module) or vga_switcheroo (kernel module, experimental) to do this in Bumblebee.

Since Bumblebee 3.0, this feature is enabled by default, using bbswitch. This allow automatic power management, without any configuration needs.

If Power Management doesn't work on your laptop, please go to [this Power Management (PM) pag](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Power-Management)e and help to improve Bumblebee.

Comment: Why do I need to install all of these packages? I can't seem to see any link that provides some info!!

Comment: You don't need them all just the 13.10 + version `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic` this is just 3 packages https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee This is the link, but its the same information, what info would you like ?

Comment: The link in your post is broken. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee