# How to switch back to Intel graphics with multi-monitor support?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel

Recently I moved to Windows 10, willing to play some games. I had to turn on some options in BIOS of my `Dell Precision 7520`, to redirect all video through `Nvidia Quadro M2200`, and to HDMI. Now I am back to Ubuntu, turned on switchable graphics in my BIOS, switched to Intel using `prime-select intel`, but can't enable my desk monitor through HDMI.

Unfortunatelly, I also used a command `prime-switch intel` not knowing exactly its purpose.

**Ubuntu 23.10**

My current BIOS settings are:

`Enable Switchable Graphics` checked

`Discrete Graphics Controller Direct Output Mode` checked

`prime-select intel`
`prime-switch intel`

How to properly configure the system to use Intel VGA (low-power consumption) and multi display?

Comment: You mention Ubuntu, but give no details as to what Ubuntu product, and what release of that *unstated* product. Why not tell us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch back to Nvidia card from Intel with Nvidia-prime](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459315/how-can-i-switch-back-to-nvidia-card-from-intel-with-nvidia-prime)

Comment: @DanielT no, as I wrote, I run this command, with no success, except that system switched to Intel, but no output to HDMI

Comment: In your question you ran the command `prime-select intel; prime-switch intel`. Clearly you only ran it because you wanted that the "system switched to Intel". If you want to switch back, you could have tried `prime-select nvidia ; prime-switch nvidia`

Comment: I don't want to switch to Nvidia. My system must run Intel, not Nvidia.

Comment: That won't work unless your laptop has a MUX switch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/hybrid_graphics

Comment: But it worked fine until yesterday.